# How to end a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT E.id_employee,E.name,E.age,E.wage,D.name,
    CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM manages M 
        WHERE M.id_employee=E.id_employee) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Chief' 
        WHEN 0 THEN '-'
    END CASE
FROM Employee E 
INNER JOIN work_in 
INNER JOIN Department D
```

it gives the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near **'CASE FROM Employee E INNER JOIN work_in INNER JOIN Department D' at line 5**

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 'CASE' after 'END'

```
SELECT E.id_employee,E.name,E.age,E.wage,D.name,
                CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM manages M WHERE M.id_employee=E.id_employee) 
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'Chief' 
                    WHEN 0 THEN '-'
                END
FROM Employee E INNER JOIN work_in INNER JOIN Department D
```

Comment: Well, not in a query... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html. It is two different CASE statement, and the OP need the one without the END CASE.

Comment: @Nik - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case disagrees with you... check the note at the end of the first bullet point.

Comment: @eykanal, that's the syntax to use **inside a stored procedure**, the syntax inside a SELECT statement ends with just END

Answer (score 4):

Remove the last CASE keyword, after the END

Answer (score 3):

Remove the word CASE from after END.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up the syntax of the [`CASE` Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) and the [`CASE` expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case). While the first one is used in stored procedures, the second one is the one used in SQL statements.

**`CASE` expression**

```
SELECT CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN 'one' WHEN 2 THEN 'two' ELSE 'more' END;
```

**`CASE` statement**

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

Or as the manual puts it

> Note
>
> The syntax of the CASE statement
>   used inside stored programs differs
>   slightly from that of the SQL CASE
>   expression described in Section 11.4,
>   “Control Flow Functions”. The CASE
>   statement cannot have an ELSE NULL
>   clause, and it is terminated with END
>   CASE instead of END.

So in your case there is no `CASE` after the `END`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `ON` condition for the [inner join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) or `USING()` clause.

```
SELECT E.id_employee,E.name,E.age,E.wage,D.name,
                CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM manages M WHERE M.id_employee=E.id_employee) 
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'Chief' 
                    WHEN 0 THEN '-'
                END
            FROM Employee E 
               INNER JOIN work_in w
                  ON e.id_employee=w.id.employee
               INNER JOIN Department D
                  ON w.id_department=D.id_department
```

Comment: You'll note the *join condition* on an `INNER JOIN` is optional: `join_table: table_reference [INNER | CROSS] JOIN table_factor [join_condition] | ...`

Comment: @Orbling--sure, it's optional, but you think query will pass the syntax check without it? It's really only optional for 2 reasons: because of the CROSS JOIN, and because you can use USING() or WHERE clause for the join conditions. He's got an inner join and no WHERE specified.

Comment: @dawebber, tested it, following query does work: `select * from table1 inner join table2;` Strangely enough it does a full outer join this way :-)

Comment: @Johan, frankly I'm surprised, but reality is reality. Obviosuly full outer join is not the expected outcome of the inner join. This is OT, but I wonder what the mySQL folks have to say about that? What sort of design forethought was in place there?

Comment: @sawebber, Errors are evil, LOL expect the unexpected?

Comment: @Johan, here's a little bit of useful info: `In MySQL, CROSS JOIN is a syntactic equivalent to INNER JOIN (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. **INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise.** ` as found [on this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html). Further, down the page: `INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the specified tables`. So, basically, INNER JOIN is a synonym for CROSS JOIN--I hinted at that in my comment @Orbling

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
"SELECT E.id_employee,E.name,E.age,E.wage,D.name,
  CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM manages M WHERE M.id_employee=E.id_employee)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Chief'                     
    WHEN 0 THEN '-'                 
  END              
FROM Employee E 
INNER JOIN work_in w ON (w.id = e.work_id)
INNER JOIN Department D ON (D.id = e.department_id)"
```

**Warning**
If you do an `inner join` with no condition(s), it will actually transform into a `full outer join`!
This means if you run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM a
INNER JOIN b
INNER JOIN c
```

where table a, b and c each have 100 rows, you will get a grand total of 1,000,000 rows in your resultset, listing every possible combination of a, b and c.
In 99,999% of the cases this is definitely not what you'd want.